# How to recreate this lecture command?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc, frame-title

Im trying to create a lecture command which will allow me to insert the lecture number which will be used to number sections, figures, and etc, and which will allow me to name the lecture. I also want the command to be able to take a date as input so and it will all be displayed in a format like this, could anyone help me recreate this or something anywhere similar to it?

[image]

Comment: You don't need a counter unless you intend to put all of the lectures into one document.  A simple macro (\thelecture) will do.  Then you need to modify \thesection, \thefigure, etc. to include this macro.  As for the heading, I believe tcolorbox or tikz does something like that easily.  Is this a slide show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses article class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datetime}
\mdyyyydate
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\thelecture}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thelecture.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thelecture.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-.667em}{\centering \textbf{\Large Lecture \thelecture}\\
  \textit{Introduction}}};
\node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west) {\footnotesize\today};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version uses `\chapter` and `\thechapter` for lectures.  Note that the table of contents starts a new page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lecturedate}[1]{\edef\@lecturedate{#1}}
\def\chaptername{Lecture}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner ysep=.3cm] (title) {\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-.667em}{\centering \textbf{\Large\chaptername~\thechapter}\\
  \textit{#1}}};
\node[fill=white, right=2pt] at (title.north west) {\footnotesize\@lecturedate};
\end{tikzpicture}\par\bigskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}% will be incremented
\lecturedate{1/1/2001}
\chapter{Introduction}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}

\section{Second}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a macro so that the whole image gets created and gets added to the toc?

Comment: I tried messing around to get the lecture to get appear on the toc with the lecture description but I couldn't figure out how to make it work, would it be possible to set the lecture at chapter level where I can set the numbering so I can perhaps skip lecture numbers, for example going from 1 to 3?

Comment: I can even use \chapter to create the image, but I would have to use report or book document class.  If there is only one lecture per document, do you really want it in the TOC?

Comment: Just tried it out and it looks great, to skip and increment chapters is all I have to do is change the counter?

Comment: Would it be possible to have the date be a variable, so I can manually enter it every time?

Comment: One can use \date{...} to set \today.  Similar to \author and \title with \maketitle.

Comment: But wouldn't that mess with every lecture, say I have multiple lectures on one doc, wouldn't changing the date change it for all lectures though? Would there be a way to manually set the lecture number and date so that I can skip lecture numbers and have different dates?

Comment: I stand corrected.  `\date` does not affect `\today`, but rather `\@date`, and it **can** be reset multiple times.

Comment: This seems to do the job, thank you so much!

Comment: I have a command in a package I made to set up my documents and when I use the command it ends up causing the date for the lecture box to end up a couple of pages before the actual lecture box itself, would you be willing to help me out with this? Heres the code for the command:

Comment: \newcommand{\start}[4]{
    \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} \date{}
    \title{\textbf{\textsc{#2}}}
    \author{\Large{#1}}
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        #4
    \end{center}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \tableofcontents
    %\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\color{Orchid}}
    \fancyhead[L]{\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark} \fancyhead[R]{#1} \fancyhead[C]{#3}}%
    %example: \start{name}{topic}{optional: class}{optional: a descriptive section} % use inside document 

}

Comment: From messing around a bit it seems like the \maketitle command is what is messing with the lecture box and causing the date be written randomly.

Comment: Both \maketitle and \tableofcontents start fresh pages in report class. Both are easily replaced. Nor do I need to use \date to set a date macro. It was just available